# Chartjs 2.8.0 in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, charts, chartjs

Trying to implement stacked bar chart to get something like path component, but several datasets and colors, something like this
[image: that's what I'm trying to get]

Using chartjs 2.8.0, added it as static resource. All the time getting an error: **chart not defined**. Implemented doughnut chart earlier using the same static resource, still working fine

**.html**

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Credit Indicators">
    <div class="slds-box">
        <canvas class="stacked1" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
        <div if:false={chart1Initialized}>
            Chart not loaded yet
        </div>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

**.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import chartjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/chartjs';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class Cmn_comp_portfolioOnAPage_CreditIndicators extends LightningElement {
chart1Initialized;

config = {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: this.data,
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
            enabled: false
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: false,
                stacked: true
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                display: false,
                stacked: true
            }]
        }
      }
  };

  data = {
    labels: [''],
    datasets: [{
        data: [50],
        //backgroundColor: "green"
        /*label: "Test",
        backgroundColor: ["blue", "red" ],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ["green", "black"]*/
    },
    {
        data: [10],
        //backgroundColor: "lightgrey"
    }]
  };

connectedCallback(){
    this.showChart1();
}

showChart1(){
    if (this.chart1Initialized) {
        return;
      }
    this.chart1Initialized = true;
    console.log('Chart initialized ' + this.chart1Initialized)
    Promise.all([
        loadScript(this, chartjs)
    ]).then(() => {
        const ctx = this.template.querySelector('canvas.stacked1').getContext('2d');
        console.log('ctx ' + ctx)
        chart = new window.Chart(ctx, this.config);


    }).catch(error => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error loading BAR Chart',
                message: error.message,
                variant: 'error',
            })
        );
    });
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    chart = new window.Chart(ctx, this.config);
```

You didn't define `chart`, so this line fails. Either declare the variable or don't use it:

```
    new window.Chart(ctx, this.config);
```

Or:

```
    const chart = new window.Chart(ctx, this.config);
```

Or:

```
chart;
showChart1(){
  // ... rest of code up to that line
  this.chart = new window.Chart(ctx, this.config);
```

This last version might be useful if you intend to manipulate the chart later.

Comment: used the first option, now do not have any errors, but have an empty canvas, no data

Comment: @AlexKoval You'll need to do some debugging. I don't see anything obvious that stands out here. My [chartjs-demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/JpN1MGsOcWbe4XG2Qx3I/src/chart.js?p=stories) might be helpful for you.